# levelplot not showing categorical classes on legend

Tags: r, r-raster, levelplot

Trying to map a categorical raster using levelplot in R, but the legend is always showing the numeric IDs as opposed to the categorical classes. See example below. Anyone encounter this issue and know what may be the problem?

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
values(r) <- rep(1:4, each=25)

r <- ratify(r) 
rat <- levels(r)[[1]]
rat$legend <- c("Class A", "Class B", "Class C", "Class D")

levels(r) <- rat

rasterVis::levelplot(r)
```

Raster map using levelplot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow with a newer version of `rasterVis` the categorical legend doesn't work (Probably a bug). You could install an older version to get the following result:

```r
library(remotes)
install_version("rasterVis", version = "0.24", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
#> Downloading package from url: http://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rasterVis/rasterVis_0.24.tar.gz

library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
values(r) <- rep(1:4, each=25)

r <- raster::ratify(r) 
rat <- levels(r)[[1]]
rat$legend <- c("Class A", "Class B", "Class C", "Class D")

levels(r) <- rat

rasterVis::levelplot(r, att = "legend")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: It is indeed a bug in version 0.51-4. It is now fixed in the development version (available from the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/oscarperpinan/rasterVis)). The version 0.51-5 will be submitted tomorrow to CRAN, so it will available there in the next days.